# Excel VBA - Populate Array with If Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to populate a combobox which works fine.

```
  lastrow = ws.Columns("C").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    v = ws.Range("C" & ws.Range("start_row_pu").Row + 1 & ":" & "R" & lastrow).Value2

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
         v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & ": " & Format(v(i, 6), "dd mmm yy") & " " & v(i, 5)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve v(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 1)
    tag_combo.List = v
```

I am looking to add an If statement so that only cells with value "Post" in column 1 should be added to the array. I have tried:

```
If v(i, 1) = "Post" then
v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & ": " & Format(v(i, 6), "dd mmm yy") & " " & v(i, 5)
End if
```

but this causes the combobox list to still load all values in Column C only.

Comment: what typeof error you get and which line

Comment: please see update

Comment: v has only c column after redim preserve line change upto r

Answer (score 0):

Right now you load a range into an array, and you want to go through the array to remove unwanted items. I know going through arrays is faster than going through cells, but just wanted to provide an alternative that should be rather fast too.

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(3))
        .AutoFilter 1, "Post"
        For Each cl In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(12)
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem cl.Value & ": " & Format(cl.Offset(0, 5), "dd mmm yy") & " " & cl.Offset(0, 4)
        Next cl
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Unfortunately we can't assign a non-contigues range to an array nor a combobox.list so we have to go through visible cells and use `.AddItem`.

Comment: ok this looks promising, but how do i set the bound column to only take column C values?

Comment: You mean...`Me.ComboBox1.AddItem cl.Value`?

Comment: when I select a value in the combobox, what would be the output? the full name of the selected text? I thought you could assign a value to each item in the combolist, using the boundcolumn property ?